# Can I write “paint 100 on a box”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If 100 is actually painted, can I say “paint 100 on a box”? Should I put 100 in quotation marks since it is text in this sentence?

Comment: If you wanted to be absolutely clear, you might write 'Paint the figures '100' on a box'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can, and yes, putting "100" in quotation marks would help to indicate that you are referring to that text specifically. In fact, the quotation marks are quite standard to make clear that you are not "using" 100 (for example, as an adjective) but are instead "[mentioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)" it.